# How to interpret Blender's SDNA structure field type index?

Tags: field, blender, file-format

As someone commented that it's impossible to dump the contents of a "`.blend`" file, I started to write a parser for "`.blend`" files ;-)
So far I can parse all the **file blocks** and the **SDNA**. However when it's about to read the file blocks' data into the corresponding structure fields, I'm running into a problem that I don't really know how to solve (due to lack of proper documentation):

If the *n*-th field of a structure has type index *i*, how do I decide whether type *i* is a structure *recursively*, or a simple type?

For example `FileGlobal` has a field `short subversion`, where the type index for `short` is 2. Obviously `short` is not a composite structure, but how does the parser decide?

In my parser's SDNA `STRC` index 2 is `ListBase`, while `TYPE` index 2 is `short`. Obviously the type index is valid in both tables, but have a different meaning...

So is my parser wrong, or what is the trick? For reference, here are some details of the SDNA I'm seeing:

```
file-header: BLENDER version 279 little-endian 64-bit ptr
...
file-block: code DNA1 size 90700 addr 55b81c6e7c80 SDNA 0 count 1
SDNA: names 4291
SDNA: NAME #0=*next
SDNA: NAME #1=*prev
SDNA: NAME #2=*data
...
SDNA: types 706
SDNA: TYPE #0=char
SDNA: TYPE #1=uchar
SDNA: TYPE #2=short
...
SDNA: TLEN #0=1
SDNA: TLEN #1=1
SDNA: TLEN #2=2
...
SDNA: structures 621
SDNA: STRC #0=stype 12 nfields 2
...
SDNA: STRC #2=stype 14 nfields 2
SDNA: STRC  field #0=ftype 11 name 3
SDNA: STRC  field #1=ftype 11 name 4
...
```

Insights?

Comment: Not really sure, but for what I remember (and `doc/blender_file_format/` directory) you never refer to structure index, only to type index. Structure itself is linked with some type though, so you get that via reverse lookup.

Comment: Reading [ https://github.com/ldo/blendhack/blob/master/blendfile.py ](blendfile.py) suggests that the parser needs to know the names of the primitive types.

Comment: It depends. Internally blender don't have to because it already have structs in C and may just copy bytes into them, the only problem is pointers, but it is the same problem for both primitive and composite types. If you want to interpret that data as numeric values in python - then you kind of have to know types, yes. Assimp have blend mesh loader too, but blendfile, doc, and builtin RNA viewer may be more reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no answer yet, I'm trying to answer my question piece-by-piece (as I learn it):

First, the `SDNA` index given in the file block seems to be the *index of the type* in the `STRC` table. However the *type number* of the type at index 0 is 12. That fixed offset (12) continues until index 12, where the type is 26. So actually you need another table (*inverted index*) that matches the *type number* to the *index of the type* in the `STRC` table.

As the first type number in that table is 12, it seems the first twelve type numbers are used for these primitive types: `char`, `uchar`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `long`, `ulong`, `float`, `double`, `int64_t`, `uint64_t`, `void`

However these types do not exist in `STRC`. So type #2 is not present in the inverted index, so it must be a primitive (non-composite) type.

Unfortunately there seem to be exceptions from the rules above: The *field types* in `STRC` are not (like the SDNA index) an index into `SDNA`, but a *type number*, so you need to use the inverted index there. When using a recursive routine to decode (like me) the routine must know whether processing a "**type index**" or a "**type number**".